# Class java.util.ArrayList has generic type parameters, use GenericTypeIndicator instead

Tags: java, android, arrays, firebase, arraylist

here's the logcat:

> 08-02 00:51:18.627 15840-15840/com.cosmichawk.classpro
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.cosmichawk.classpro, PID: 15840
>       com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class java.util.ArrayList has generic type parameters, please use
>   GenericTypeIndicator instead
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzb(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zza(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzb(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzku.zza(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzb(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zza(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
>           at com.cosmichawk.classpro.MainActivity$6.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:205)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzfc.zza(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzgx.zzdr(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzhd.run(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6186)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)

And the main activity:

> package com.cosmichawk.classpro;
>
> import android.content.Intent; import
>   android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog; import
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; import android.os.Bundle;
>   import android.text.TextUtils; import android.view.LayoutInflater;
>   import android.view.View; import android.widget.AdapterView; import
>   android.widget.ArrayAdapter; import android.widget.Button; import
>   android.widget.EditText; import android.widget.ListView; import
>   android.widget.Spinner; import android.widget.Toast;
>
> import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot; import
>   com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError; import
>   com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference; import
>   com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase; import
>   com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
>
> import java.util.ArrayList; import java.util.List;
>
> public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
>       public static final String ARTIST_NAME = "com.cosmichawk.classpro.artistname";
>       public static final String ARTIST_ID = "com.cosmichawk.classpro.artistid";
>
> ```
> EditText editTextName,editTextAmount, editTextNumber;
> Button buttonAddArtist;
> ArrayList array;
> ListView listViewArtists;
>
> //a list to store all the artist from firebase database
> List<Artist> artists;
>
> //our database reference object
> DatabaseReference databaseArtists;
>
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>
>     //getting the reference of artists node
>     databaseArtists = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("artists");
>
>     //getting views
>     editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
>     editTextAmount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAmount);
>     editTextNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNumber);
>
>     listViewArtists = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewArtists);
>
>     buttonAddArtist = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddArtist);
>
>     //list to store artists
>     artists = new ArrayList<>();
>
>
>     //adding an onclicklistener to button
>     buttonAddArtist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View view) {
>             //calling the method addArtist()
>             //the method is defined below
>             //this method is actually performing the write operation
>             addArtist();
>         }
>     });
>
>     //attaching listener to listview
>     listViewArtists.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
>             //getting the selected artist
>             Artist artist = artists.get(i);
>
>             //creating an intent
>             Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ArtistActivity.class);
>
>             //putting artist name and id to intent
>             intent.putExtra(ARTIST_ID, artist.getArtistId());
>             intent.putExtra(ARTIST_NAME, artist.getArtistName());
>
>             //starting the activity with intent
>             startActivity(intent);
>         }
>     });
>
>     listViewArtists.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
>             Artist artist = artists.get(i);
>             showUpdateDeleteDialog(artist.getArtistId(), artist.getArtistName());
>             return true;
>         }
>     });
>
>
> }
>
> private void showUpdateDeleteDialog(final String artistId, String artistName) {
>
>     AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
>     LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
>     final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.update_dialog, null);
>     dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
>
>     final EditText editTextName = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
>     final EditText editTextAmount = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editTextAmount);
>     final EditText editTextNumber = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editTextNumber);
>     final Button buttonUpdate = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.buttonUpdateArtist);
>     final Button buttonDelete = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.buttonDeleteArtist);
>
>     dialogBuilder.setTitle(artistName);
>     final AlertDialog b = dialogBuilder.create();
>     b.show();
>
>
>     buttonUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View view) {
>             String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
>             String amount = editTextAmount.getText().toString().trim();
>             String number = editTextNumber.getText().toString().trim();
>             int fb = Integer.parseInt(amount);
>             int rl = Integer.parseInt(number);
>             int m = fb / rl;
>             ArrayList array=new ArrayList();
>
>
>
>
>
>             if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
>
>                 for(int l=0; l<rl; l++){
>                     array.add(l,m);
>                 }
>                 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), array+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>                 updateArtist(artistId, name, amount, number, array);
>                 b.dismiss();
>             }
>
>         }
>     });
>
>
>
>     buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View view) {
>
>             deleteArtist(artistId);
>             b.dismiss();
>         }
>     });
> }
>
> private boolean updateArtist(String id, String name, String amount, String number, ArrayList array) {
>     //getting the specified artist reference
>     DatabaseReference dR = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("artists").child(id);
>
>     //updating artist
>     Artist artist = new Artist(id, name, amount, number, array);
>     dR.setValue(artist);
>     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Artist Updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>     return true;
> }
>
> private boolean deleteArtist(String id) {
>     //getting the specified artist reference
>     DatabaseReference dR = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("artists").child(id);
>
>     //removing artist
>     dR.removeValue();
>
>     //getting the tracks reference for the specified artist
>     DatabaseReference drTracks = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("tracks").child(id);
>
>     //removing all tracks
>     drTracks.removeValue();
>     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Artist Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>
>     return true;
> }
>
> @Override
> protected void onStart() {
>     super.onStart();
>     //attaching value event listener
>     databaseArtists.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
>
>             //clearing the previous artist list
>             artists.clear();
>
>             //iterating through all the nodes
>             for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
>                 //getting artist
>
>
>                 Artist artist = postSnapshot.getValue(Artist.class);
>                 //adding artist to the list
>                 artists.add(artist);
>             }
>
>             //creating adapter
>             ArtistList artistAdapter = new ArtistList(MainActivity.this, artists);
>             //attaching adapter to the listview
>             listViewArtists.setAdapter(artistAdapter);
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
>
>         }
>     });
> }
>
>
> /*
>  * This method is saving a new artist to the
>  * Firebase Realtime Database
>  * */
> private void addArtist() {
>     //getting the values to save
>     String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
>     String amount = editTextAmount.getText().toString().trim();
>     String number = editTextNumber.getText().toString().trim();
>     int fb = Integer.parseInt(amount);
>     int rl = Integer.parseInt(number);
>     int m = fb / rl;
>
>     ArrayList array = new ArrayList();
>
>     for(int l=0; l<rl; l++){
>         array.add(l,m);
>     }
>
>     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), array+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>     //checking if the value is provided
>     if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
>
>         //getting a unique id using push().getKey() method
>         //it will create a unique id and we will use it as the Primary Key for our Artist
>         String id = databaseArtists.push().getKey();
>
>         //creating an Artist Object
>         Artist artist = new Artist(id, name, amount, number, array);
>
>         //Saving the Artist
>         databaseArtists.child(id).setValue(artist);
>
>         //setting edittext to blank again
>         editTextName.setText("");
>         editTextAmount.setText("");
>         editTextNumber.setText("");
>
>
>         //displaying a success toast
>         Toast.makeText(this, "Artist added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>     } else {
>         //if the value is not given displaying a toast
>         Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>     }
> } }
> ```

Also, Artist.java equipped with its empty constructor

> package com.cosmichawk.classpro;
>
> import com.google.firebase.database.IgnoreExtraProperties;
>
> import java.sql.Array; import java.util.ArrayList;
>
> @IgnoreExtraProperties public class Artist {
>       private String artistId;
>       private String artistName;
>       private String artistAmount;
>       private String artistNumber;
>       private ArrayList artistArray;
>
> ```
> public Artist(){
>     //this constructor is required
> }
>
> public Artist(String artistId, String artistName, String artistAmount, String artistNumber, ArrayList artistArray) {
>     this.artistId = artistId;
>     this.artistName = artistName;
>     this.artistAmount = artistAmount;
>     this.artistNumber = artistNumber;
>     this.artistArray = artistArray;
>
>
> }
>
> public String getArtistId() {
>     return artistId;
> }
>
> public String getArtistName() {
>     return artistName;
> }
>
> public String getArtistAmount() {
>     return artistAmount;
> }
>
> public String getArtistNumber() { return artistNumber; }
>
> public ArrayList getArtistArray() { return artistArray; } }
> ```

This is what my database looks like:-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caKjV.png)

Comment: I would really appreciate if you mark my answer as the accepted answer. Thanks

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: Added the database structure

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the type

```
artists = new ArrayList<Artist>();
```

The cleaner way to do this is initialize artists in the declaration space

So instead of

```
List<Artist> artists;
```

you can do this

```
List<Artist> artists = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: This time the array is displayed but the application force closes with the exact same errors